# How to compile to an APK

Tags: android

I am using VS 2022. In the past I have compiled my Android (Xamarin) code and deployed an APK. Now (18 months later) I need to make a change. When I build the code I just get a DLL and an PDB. No APK. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should tag this with more than "andriod" (add "visual-studio" and "xamarin.android").

Answer (score 0):

Just recalled: Build, Go to Solution Explorer -> Android project (right click) --> Archive --> Distribute -- AdHoc --> Sign & Add Details --> Save As.

(from a Google search)